# Change color of bar plots

Tags: r, plotly

I have a plot:

```
p <- plot_ly(
  x = c(data$sum),
  y = c(data$candidate),
  name = "Trump v Clinton",
  type = "bar"
)
```

`Candidate` is realDonaldTrump and HilaryClinton while sum is 10000 and 5000.

Is it possible to set the colour for the bar of each candidate? I.e. Trump be red and Hilary blue.

Comment: Adding an argument `color = ~candidate` serves your purpose. You should have your data (a `data.frame`) and the line of code can be `p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~sum, y = ~candidate, type = "bar", name = "Trump v Clinton", color =~candidate)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for something like this?:

```
library(plotly)

data<-data.frame(sum=c(10000, 5000), candidate=c("DonaldTrump", "HilaryClinton"))
data$color<-c("red", "blue")

p <- plot_ly(
  y = data$sum,
  x = data$candidate,
  color = I(data$color),
  type = "bar"
)
p<-layout(p, title = "Trump vs Clinton")
print(p)
```

It plot as a vertical barplot, I needed to swap the values for the x and y axis.

Comment: colors of your bars are green and blue and not red and blue as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
library(plotly)
data.frame(sum=c(10000, 5000), candidate=c("DonaldTrump", "HilaryClinton")) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = candidate, y = sum, type = "bar", color = candidate)
```

[image]